# Como fazer uma consulta SQL via Socket?

Tags: c#, sql, socket

Como fazer com que o cliente passe uma consulta pro servidor e então retorne o que o cliente requisitou?

Exemplo: O cliente passa pro servidor a string: `sql = "Select nome From Aluno";` e o servidor teria que retornar o nome ou os nomes dos alunos cadastrados no banco.

Como fazer?

Comment: Por socket? isso é uma exigência ou poderia ser feita via JDBC mesmo?

Comment: Sim, somente por socket.

Comment: Qual o intuito disso? @VictorLauria

Comment: O intuito é concluir um trabalho acadêmico, @jbueno.

Comment: E o seu trabalho é especificamente sobre _sockets_?

Comment: Não somente sockets, preciso desenvolver uma aplicação que use sockets, wcf e xml persistence.

Comment: Neste caso você teria de criar 2 aplicações, Uma cliente e uma servidor, A servidor faria a comunicação com o Banco de Dados e a Cliente faria a requisição e receberia a resposta, A parte da conexão com o Banco e tudo mais você ja sabe fazer?